# Optional/required parts of forms

Tags: php, html, forms

I am just new to PHP and HTML, and have a working form. Now I am trying to add features to it. The form is basically called multiple times to submit photos for a photo competition. The form asks for the author's name, and the file to upload. After it processes that, it displays the form again for more photos to be uploaded.

This is what it looks like so far, and it seems to work.

```
<?php
if (array_key_exists('Submitted',$_POST)) {
    $photoCategory = $_POST['Category'];

    $authorFirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
    $authorLastName = $_POST['LastName'];
//  Process the form data here...
    echo "If you have more photos to submit, continue below.<br>";
    echo "If you have finished, just close this window.<br>";
}
?>

<!-- Set up the form -->
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="Submitted" value="true">

    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="FirstName" size="20"> required<br>

    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="LastName" size="20" required><br>

    <label>File 1 to upload</label>
    <input type="file" name="Photo1"><br>

    <label> </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"><br>
</form>
```

So my questions are:

1. Is this structure a sensible way to approach this?
2. If so, how can I get the person's name set as the default values for the second and subsequent instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Sure
2. You can echo them out as default values in the form. Alternatively, you could save them to the `$_SESSION` and reference that value during your process. Same goes for category.

Note the `value` attribute added to the inputs:

```
<?php
if (array_key_exists('Submitted',$_POST)) {
    $photoCategory = $_POST['Category'];

    $authorFirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
    $authorLastName = $_POST['LastName'];
//  Process the form data here...
    echo "If you have more photos to submit, continue below.<br>";
    echo "If you have finished, just close this window.<br>";
}
?>

<!-- Set up the form -->
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="Submitted" value="true">

    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="<?php echo $_POST['FirstName'] ?? ''; ?>" size="20"> required<br>

    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="LastName" value="<?php echo $_POST['LastName'] ?? ''; ?>" size="20" required><br>

    <label>File 1 to upload</label>
    <input type="file" name="Photo1"><br>

    <label> </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after. I had tried something like this but had omitted the "echo".

As for category, it is a drop down menu. It does not seem to work for me. It always goes back to the default value.

  <select name="Category" required value= <?php echo $photoCategory; ?> >
   <option value="Landscape">Landscape</option>
   <option value="Nature">Nature</option>
   <option value="SpiritofBushwalking">Spirit of Bushwalking</option>
   <option value="HandofMan">Hand of Man</option>
  </select>

Comment: Ugh! I have that code wrong.

<select name="Category" required value= "<?php echo $photoCategory; ?>" > <option value="Landscape">Landscape</option> <option value="Nature">Nature</option> <option value="SpiritofBushwalking">Spirit of Bushwalking</option> <option value="HandofMan">Hand of Man</option> </select>

Comment: Worked it out. You cannot have "required" with a default value.

Comment: Now it is not working. :-( Obviously something more subtle is involved.

Comment: Anyone not running under PHP 7.0 will have to rewrite this using a different ternary operator. This should have been noted in the answer. Then again, many (new) coders won't know what went wrong and how to fix it once they notice something didn't work.

Comment: Hey @Fred-ii- long time no see! Haha, yeah I've dropped support for PHP 5 ;) How you been?

Comment: Hey @JeffPuckett it's been a while. I've been pretty busy with house-related things *lol!*. It's nice to take a break from coding every once in a while, I hope you are well.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand your first question - semantically. You could rephrase it, regarding the "sensible way".

Your page design is good. Make sure that you're not mixing the server superglobals ($_GET, $_POST, etc) inside the html part of your webpage. In general, the code inside the php tags in the html part should only present normal variables and short statements. So, one should never see something like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo '/abc/' . $path1 . '/def=' . (100+0.53) . '&id=' . getId(); ?>">
```

or like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $_POST['url']; ?>">
```

but only like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"
```

An important thing is, that you should ensure not only the validation of the input values on the client-side (javascript, jQuery, etc), but also on the server-side (PHP). As much validation as possible is very good.

Otherwise, try to maintain the "camelCase" notation not only for the php variables, but also for the values of the html attributes. The css classes should be noted like this `class="my-perfect-notation"`. Also, read [this](https://www.butterfly.com.au/blog/website-development/clean-high-quality-code-a-guide-on-how-to-become-a-better-programmer), [this](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) and [this](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/). The second link is especially important (easy to read too).

As for the second question, the code for setting the default values is straight-forward: if a posted value is set, then print it, otherwise print an empty string.

Good luck!

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitButton'])) {
    $authorFirstName = isset($_POST['firstName']) ? $_POST['firstName'] : '';
    $authorLastName = isset($_POST['lastName']) ? $_POST['lastName'] : '';
    $photoCategory = isset($_POST['photoCategory']) ? $_POST['photoCategory'] : '';

    // Input data validations.
    if (empty($authorFirstName)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please provide the first name.';
    }

    if (empty($authorLastName)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please provide the last name.';
    }

    if (empty($photoCategory)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please provide the photo category.';
    }

    // Input data processing.
    if (!isset($errors)) {
        // ...

        $message = 'If you have more photos to submit, continue below.<br/>';
        $message .= 'If you have finished, just close this window.<br/><br/>';
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Photo upload</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            .error {
                padding: 10px;
                margin-bottom: 15px;
                width: 400px;
                color: #c94e4e;
                background-color: #fcc9c9;
            }

            .message {
                margin-bottom: 15px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php
        // Display errors list.
        if (isset($errors)) {
            foreach ($errors as $error) {
                ?>
                <div class="error">
                    <?php echo $error; ?>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>

        <?php
        // Display message.
        if (isset($message)) {
            ?>   
            <div class="message">
                <?php echo $message; ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>

        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="firstName">First Name *</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" value="<?php echo isset($authorFirstName) ? $authorFirstName : ''; ?>" size="20" required>
            <br/><br/>

            <label for="lastName">Last Name *</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" value="<?php echo isset($authorLastName) ? $authorLastName : ''; ?>" size="20" required>
            <br/><br/>

            <label for="photoCategory">Photo category</label>
            <select id="photoCategory" name="photoCategory" value= "<?php echo $photoCategory; ?>" >
                <option value="Landscape">Landscape</option>
                <option value="Nature">Nature</option>
                <option value="SpiritofBushwalking">Spirit of Bushwalking</option>
                <option value="HandofMan">Hand of Man</option>
            </select>
            <br/><br/>

            <label for="photo">Photo upload</label>
            <input type="file" id="photo" name="photo">
            <br/><br/>

            <button type="submit" name="submitButton">
                Upload
            </button>
            <br/><br/>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I left out the CSS deliberately to improve clarity in what I was asking.

Comment: @DavidM I thought so. But I wanted you to know how. Bye.